# Shifting rows and inserting zeros in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to automatically convert a 40x40 excel sheet to 64x40 using openpyxl. I want to insert 3x40 zeros in between each 5 rows of values. I've tried a lot of code but none are working or giving me the correct results.

The only thing that was close enough gave me only one 3x40 zeros after the first 5 rows of values.

Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtmhn.png)

How I want it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OuOR.png)

It would be great if anyone could guide me on how it can be done.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should achieve what you want

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

### Range starting at [row] 6 and stepping 8 (5+3) to the end of used rows
for r in range(6, ws.max_row, 8):
    ### Insert 3 rows at row r
    ws.insert_rows(r, 3)
    # Populate the newly inserted rows with value 0
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=r, max_row=r+2, max_col=ws.max_column):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = 0

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```